# Chrome Extension Get User's Password For Website

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, passwords

I'm fooling around with Chrome Extensions, and was wondering.

Is it possible to get the a password for a website that's saved by Google Chrome (as in, it's autosaved password feature)?

It would be cumbersome to have a button in the bar just to login to the website, and would be annoying to prompt the user every time the password is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so far as I know, you can NOT do what you want to.

but, you can develop a extension, which stores your password itself by using chrome.storage API or localStorage API of html5.

and then, when you open a website page, you extension read your password from storage of it, fill it in to corresponding website. logging automatically.

just a idea. By using chrome.storage.sync,  your data can be synchronized between your devices those use chrome with your extension and your google account.

thx the comment. the data can not be encrypted, so think twice before you work with my answer.

sorry for that.

Comment: "By using chrome.storage.sync, your password will be encrypted," - This statement is **false**. [The documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#using-sync) explicitly states "Confidential user information should not be stored! The storage area isn't encrypted."